# How do I customise gmaps4rails sidebar's UL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I have to be able to change the UL CSS bullet style in the gmaps4rails sidebar.

In my view:

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"list_container" => "markers_list" }}) if session[:user_id] %>
```

In my CSS file I tried this:

```
#markers_list {
    ul {
        list-style-type: square;
        font-size:9px;
    }
    li {
        font-size:9px;
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to work.

I figure there was may be a custom_sidebar_class but it doesn't like it.

Hope you can help,

Cheers,

Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to customize the sidebar and I don't think I'll implement it because it's pretty easy for anyone to do it:

In the callback, loop the markers and get inspiration from [this really short function](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee#L372).